# Can't publish to Docker Hub from Visual Studio

Tags: docker

Docker .NetCore app running in a container runs fine in Visual Studio.  When I try to publish to Docker Hub, it returns an “unknown” error (log below).

The profile is set to my user and pw (for Docker Hub).  When viewing in VS, on the Publish screen there is a url to the base Docker Hub directory. Clicking on it returns a “not found” error from Docker Hub.  Any ideas on what would cause this?  I did check to make sure I was logged in with Docker Desktop, if that matters.

From VS:
Publish has encountered an error.
Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

> Log: at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__213.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the
>   output log for more details. <---
>
> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to
>   determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more
>   details.
>
> ===================

Comment: Can you please provide more information from your output log?

Comment: Add the actual code (docker command, docker file, etc)

Comment: I may have figured it out. I will post more info when I'm sure. Thanks!